# nginx: How to handle 404 directly in a reverse proxy for some filenames (*.txt) only?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a complex `nginx` setup where a front `nginx` at ports 80 and 443 handles all outside access including TLS.

For files in `/texts` the frontend-nginx shall proxy request to a second backend-nginx which modifies existing text files on the fly in a complicated process, using up CPU and other resources.

For those files `*.txt` that do not exist (404) I wish not to bother the backend at all but instead provide the client with a default file `/texts/default.txt` directly.  However, currently non-existing files are still only handled in the backend's `error_page  404` line.  Existing files are served without a problem, the proxy works.

This is my config:

```
frontend-nginx.conf:
http {
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  frontend.example.org;
        root         /srv/www;

        location /texts/ {

            location ~ \*.txt$ {
                root /srv/www/backend;

                ####### the next line has absolutely no effect
                try_files $uri /texts/default.txt;
            }

            proxy_pass          http://localhost:90;
            proxy_redirect      http://localhost:90/ /;
            proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection       "upgrade";
            proxy_http_version  1.1;

            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
    # https goes here, all the same except TLS
}
```

```
backend-nginx.conf:
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;

    server {
        listen       127.0.0.1:90;

        root /srv/www/backend;
        charset utf-8;

        expires -1;  # no-cache
        location ~ /..*\.txt$ {
            # longer cache time for text files
            expires 10m;

            # this actually works but only here in the backend
            error_page  404 @404;
        }

        location @404 {
            return 302 $scheme://frontend.example.org/texts/default.txt
        }
    }
}
```

I have that useless statement in the frontend config file which looks to me as if it could handle 404 redirects to `default.txt` but when I do

```
wget -v http://frontend.example.org/texts/notexist.txt
```

I get a redirect only inside the backend (so proxying does take place).

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks but I am afraid that does not work. I also do `root /srv/www/texts;` before that so it should be enough?  Anyway, the backend does get called which it shouldn't if the path is wrong?

Comment: @RichardSmith You are right, the `root` statements were chaotic, I have made them more logical. `/texts` is part of the pathname but never part of `root`; the two `nginx` instances have differing `root`.  Now, the logs still show that the non-existing txt-file will be requested from the backend, which is not what I want.

Comment: @RichardSmith Sorry, I have condensed the problem and config files to a minimum. The backend actually uses server-side scripting to modify these files on the fly, using up CPU and other resources. Therefore I do not wish to activate it for a simple 404. Edited the question so that the whole seems better motivated. It is.

Comment: So if the backend has a file called `foo.txt` which is accessed using the URI `/texts/foo.txt` it can be seen by the frontend at `/srv/www/backend/texts/foo.txt`. If you can confirm that, I will attempt an answer.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, it can be seen by the frontend but shall not be served. Existing files need to go through proxy/backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
location /texts/ {
    proxy_set_header ...;
    proxy_pass ...;

    location ~ \.txt$ {
        root /path/to/root;
        try_files $uri /texts/default.txt;
        proxy_pass ...;
    }
}
location = /texts/default.txt {
    root /path/to/root;
}
```

Notice the correct regular expression for the `location` statement. The `proxy_set_header` statements will be inherited, but the `proxy_pass` statement needs to be repeated in the nested `location`.

The `try_files` statement will check for the existence of the file and change the URI if it does not exist.

The default file has a dedicated `location` so that the file can be served as a static file from the correct root.

The path to the file is constructed by concatenating the value of `root` with the URI, so the file `/texts/default.txt` is located at `/path/to/root/texts/default.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, will test and let you know tomorrow.